# high load and OOM-killer on domUs while pvmove

Tags: xen, lvm, oom, ionice

### Situation

- xen 4.0.1 dom0 (debian squeeze)
- domUs all with LVs as disks: `disk = [ 'phy:/dev/vg-00/domu-swap,xvda1,w', 'phy:/dev/vg-00/domu-disk,xvda2,w' ]`)
- one VG (`vg-00`) with 2 PVs

### Goal

- Move all LVs from one PV to the other (pvmove) and remove the "empty" PV (vgreduce)
- Not disturbing any running machine (domU od Dom0)

### Problem(s)

When i start `pmove` (i even tried to `ionice -c3` it) my domUs get very high loads or even get stuck. I think this happens, when `pvmove` is moving the extends from the domUs LV from one PV to the other. I also saw the domU really freaking out an fireing the OOM-killer. Long story short: i had to interupt the procedure (`pvmove --abort`), because my domU(s) started to get unusable, major server components were killed or they even died/froze completely.

### Questions

- I'm aware of higher IO loads while the transition and can cope with this. But even when `ionice -c3`d the IO load is so high, that inside the domU tasks get blocked. Why isn't the `ionice` working here? If i understand this correct, all IO is done by the dom0 (by the blkback driver) so the dom0 should see all IO done by every dom(0|U) and should be able toschedule IO for my `renice` process - are my assumptions wrong here?
- Why does my domU fire up the OOM-killer? How can this process affect the domU's memory? BTW: when the domUs go crazy my dom0 works fine. High IO, but that's obvious.
- Is there any way to remove one PV without the hassel above? Would it be better to shutdown/pause one domU after the other and pvmove only LVs from this machine?

Thank you in advance for every input - i even would be glad to get some "debugging ideas"!

Answer (score 0):

It should work - but it seems that XEN imposes some kind of exclusive locking in "w" mode. Perhaps that locking is not that strict in "w!" (or was is "!w"?) mode. That mode should allow write requests from more than one source.

Which memory cosumption goes up before the killer kicks in in the DomU? Buffer memory?

Comment: I don't really understand, why 'w!' should make a difference, but i will give it a try. I can't really tell, which memory consumption was going up - as i noticed the oom killer kicking in, i aborted the whole process. But next time i will look into this ... Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: You are welcome. Please keep us updated. I could get into situations where I would try the same what you did...

Comment: Yesterday i moved some of my LVs. I moved one LV after the other (`pvmove -n lvname ...`). Most of them moved fine - had no drastic impact on any machine. Now i have 4 LVs left (unfortunately the biggest ones). When i try to move them, load on a domU (always the same one(s)) rises, machine is stuck and i have to abort. Will investigate ... P.S.: Thist was done with running domUs and 'w'-disks